# BSON structure created by Apache Spark and MongoDB Hadoop-Connector

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to save some JSON from Spark (Scala) to MongoDB using the MongoDB Hadoop-Connector.  The problem I'm having is that this API always seems to save your data as "{_id: ..., value:  {your JSON document}}".

In the code example below, my document gets saved like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e80cfea9fbee30aa703261"),
    "value" : {
        "_id" : "55e6c65da9fbee285f2f9175",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 5,
        "day" : 6,
        "hour" : 18,
        "user_id" : 246
    }
}
```

Is there any way to persuade the MongoDB Hadoop Connector to write the JSON/BSON in the structure you've specified, instead of nesting it under these _id/value fields?

Here's my Scala Spark code:

```
  val jsonstr = List("""{
        "_id" : "55e6c65da9fbee285f2f9175",
        "year" : 2014,
        "month" : 5,
        "day" : 6,
        "hour" : 18,
        "user_id" : 246}""")

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Mongo Dummy").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  // DB params
  val host = "127.0.0.1"
  val port = "27017"
  val database = "dummy"
  val collection = "fubar"

  // input is collection we want to read (not doing so here)
  val mongo_input = s"mongodb://$host/$database.$collection"
  // output is collection we want to write
  val mongo_output = s"mongodb://$host/$database.$collection"

  // Set up extra config for Hadoop connector
  val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()

  //hadoopConfig.set("mongo.input.uri", mongo_input)
  hadoopConfig.set("mongo.output.uri", mongo_output)

  // convert JSON to RDD
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(jsonstr)

  // write JSON data to DB
  val saveRDD = rdd.map { json =>
    (null, Document.parse(json))
  }

  saveRDD.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///bogus",
    classOf[Object],
    classOf[BSONObject],
    classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]],
    hadoopConfig)
  // Finished  
  sc.stop
```

And here's my SBT:

```
name := "my-mongo-test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

// Spark needs to appear in SBT BEFORE Mongodb connector!
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.4.0"

// MongoDB-Hadoop connector
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop" % "mongo-hadoop-core" % "1.4.0"
```

To be honest, I'm kind of mystified at how hard it seems to be to save JSON --> BSON --> MongoDB from Spark.  So any suggestions on how to save my JSON data more flexibly would be welcomed.

Comment: How about saving directly from `mapPartitions`?

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  So that would mean doing something like "saveRDD.mapPartitions(mySaveToMongoFunction(..)), right?

Comment: And would I then be able to use a regular MongoDB driver e.g. Casbah or ReactiveMongo inside this function? I'm not sure how Spark would handle the driver interactions here - or would it just end up blocking on the driver calls?  I thought the point of using the MongoDB Hadoop Connector is supposed to be that it is partition-aware and handles the driver interaction accordingly.  But if I can do this myself using mapPartitions() then that sounds like a good solution.

Comment: Exactly, you can use regular MongoDB tools. I am more worried about MongoDB part though. Depending on a version / engine you use a write lock can be a limiting part, but I doubt Hadoop Connector can do something significantly better. Another possible issue is that you have to handle failures manually.

Comment: OK, that sounds like a good plan. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just found the solution. It turns out that **MongoRecordWriter** which is used by **MongoOutputFormat** inserts any value that does **not** inherit from **BSONWritable** or **MongoOutput** or **BSONObject** under *value* field.

The most simple solution, therefore, is to create RDD that contain **BSONObject** as a value, rather than **Document**.

I tried this solution in Java, but I'm sure it will work in Scala as well. Here is a sample code:

```
JavaPairRDD<Object, BSONObject> bsons = values.mapToPair(lineValues -> {
    BSONObject doc = new BasicBSONObject();
    doc.put("field1", lineValues.get(0));
    doc.put("field2", lineValues.get(1));
    return new Tuple2<Object, BSONObject>(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), doc);
});

Configuration outputConfig = new Configuration();
outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
                 "mongodb://localhost:27017/my_db.lines");
bsons.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile("file:///this-is-completely-unused"
        , Object.class
        , BSONObject.class
        , MongoOutputFormat.class
        , outputConfig);
```